# Sorting + Pagination in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to find a solution to allow users to sort content that is being output by a CMS while maintaining pagination.

I've got 50+ articles, and after 10 articles, I need to start pagination.  I've found several jQuery plugins that handle pagination no problem.

I'll have a dropdown with options so the user can sort the info (Oldest to newest, A-Z, newest to oldest).

The info is not presented in tables, but rather content is in divs, like this:

```
<label for="sort">Sort</label>
<select name="sort">
<option value="A-Z">A-Z</option>
<option value="Oldest to Newest">Oldest to Newest</option>
<option value="Newest to Oldest">Newest to Oldest</option>
</select>

<div>
<h1>Cool Title Here</h1>
<p class="date">6-5-10</p>
<p>Content Goes Here.  <a href="#">read more</a></p>
</div>

<div>
<h1>It rains in Spain</h1>
<p class="date">5-8-10</p>
<p>Content Goes Here.  <a href="#">read more</a></p>
</div>

<div>
<h1>Another Cool Title</h1>
<p class="date">4-15-10</p>
<p>Content Goes Here.  <a href="#">read more</a></p>
</div>

Pagination Options will go here.
```

Not sure if anyone has found a solution that is able to tackle both of these issues.

Comment: Hmm... I thought of 3 plug-ins that also include searching, but they all use tables.  I'll keep looking, though.

Comment: Also, do you want the sorting to be for the current selection only, or across all articles?

Comment: Hey Levi...thnx for your response.  yeh, everything i've looked at involves table sorting :(  The sorting will be for all the article intros that are listed out (as in the format above).  did i give you enough info?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who posted above.  I just went ahead and hired someone to do this through my CMS since I was under a time crunch.  Turns out through PHP the developer was able to get this functionality working.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort a jquery object - in this case the divs from the content management system - by using the sort method with a function as an argument. In this case I've used the jquery .find method to sort based on the text of the elements within the parent divs.

If you're going to be sorting a large number of elements then you might potentially run into performance issues on older browsers and might have to use another function to sort.

I've included the original HTML underneath the script - I added a parent container element for the CMS divs and some pagination controls. Hope this helps!

```
    <script>
   var pageSize = 10; //sets number of results shown at a time
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#selectSort").change(function() {
           switch ($(this).val()) {
               case "A-Z":
                   $("#CMSContent div").sort(sortTitle).appendTo($("#CMSContent").empty());
                   break;

               case "Oldest to Newest":
                   $($.makeArray($("#CMSContent div").sort(sortDate)).reverse()).appendTo($("#CMSContent").empty());
                   break;

               case "Newest to Oldest":
                   $("#CMSContent div").sort(sortDate).appendTo($("#CMSContent").empty());
                   break;
           }
           displayResults(0); //initial sort
       });

       $("#first").click(function() { displayResults(0); });

       $("#previous").click(function() { displayPreviousPage(); });

       $("#next").click(function() { displayNextPage(); });

       $("#last").click(function() {
           displayResults($("#CMSContent div").length - ($("#CMSContent div").length % pageSize));
       });
       $("#selectSort").change(); //initial sort
   });

   function displayNextPage() {
       displayResults($("#CMSContent div:visible:first").prevAll().length + pageSize);
   }

   function displayPreviousPage() {
       displayResults($("#CMSContent div:visible:first").prevAll().length - pageSize);
   }
   function displayResults(start) {
       if (start < 0) { start = 0; }
       $("#CMSContent div")
            .css("display", "none") //hide all elements
            .slice(start, start + pageSize).css("display", "block"); //displays elements in page
       //show and hide pagination controls as necessary
       $("#next, #last").css("visibility", (start + pageSize > $("#CMSContent div").length ? "hidden" : ""));
       $("#previous, #first").css("visibility", (start == 0 ? "hidden" : ""));
   }

   function sortTitle(a, b) {
       return $(b).find("h1").text() < $(a).find("h1").text();
   }
   function sortDate(a, b) {
       return formatDate($(b).find("p.date").text()) > formatDate($(a).find("p.date").text());
   }
   function formatDate(txt) { //assumes all dates in mm-dd-yyyy format and post 2000
       var d = new Date();
       d.setFullYear(parseInt("20" + txt.split("-")[2]));
       d.setMonth(parseInt(txt.split("-")[0]) - 1, parseInt(txt.split("-")[1]));
       return d;
   }
</script>


<label for="sort">
    Sort</label>
<select name="sort" id="selectSort">
    <option value="A-Z">A-Z</option>
    <option value="Oldest to Newest">Oldest to Newest</option>
    <option value="Newest to Oldest">Newest to Oldest</option>
</select>
<div id="CMSContent">
    <div>
        <h1>
            Cool Title Here</h1>
        <p class="date">
            6-5-10</p>
        <p>
            Content Goes Here. <a href="#">read more</a></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>
            It rains in Spain</h1>
        <p class="date">
            5-8-10</p>
        <p>
            Content Goes Here. <a href="#">read more</a></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>
            Another Cool Title</h1>
        <p class="date">
            4-15-10</p>
        <p>
            Content Goes Here. <a href="#">read more</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="first" type="button" value="First" />
<input id="previous" type="button" value="Previous" />
<input id="next" type="button" value="Next" />
<input id="last" type="button" value="Last" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you do not find a plugin you can write some custom js.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myDivContentArray = new Array();
    var sortedContents = new Array();
    var size = 0;
    var pageSize = 10;
    //var currentPageNumber = 1;
    var tempContent = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").each(function(index){
            //debugger;
            tempContent["Index"] = index;
            tempContent["Title"] = $(this).find("h1").html();
            tempContent["Date"]= Date.Parse($(this).find(".date").html());
            //need to parse milliseconds to current time
            tempContent["Content"] = $(this).find("p:last").html();
            $(this).hide();
            myDivContentArray.push(tempContent);
        });
        $(".pageNumber").live("click",Changepage($(this).val()));
        size = myDivContentArray.length;
        for(i = 0; i< size/pageSize; i++)
        {
            $("select[name=Sort]").append("<label value="+i+" class='pageNumber' ></label>");
        }

    });
    $("label[for=sort]").click(function(){
        var selectedOption = $("select[name=sort]").val();
        switch(selectedOption)
        {
            case "A-Z": { sortedContents = myDivContentArray.sort(sortAlpha); break; }
            case "Oldest to Newest": { sortedContents = myDivContentArray.sort(sortDate).reverse(); break; }
            case "Newest to Oldest": { sortedContents = myDivContentArray.sort(sortDate); break; }
        }
        Changepage(1);
    });
    function Changepage(pageNumber)
    {
        //Show only those divs whose Index is in the sortedContents array
    }
    function sortDate(a,b){  
        return a["Date"] > b["Date"] ? 1 : -1;  
    };
    function sortAlpha(a,b) {
        return (a["Title"] > b["Title"]) ? 1: -1;
    }
    </script>
```

Inside the ChangePage function you can loop through all the divs and make only those divs visible whose Index is in the sortedArray. 
I have not tested this script completely. So debug it once.